Expiry year validity in @stripe/stripe-react-native
I have integrated @stripe/stripe-react-native in my app which is working fine is happy scanarios.
<CardField
postalCodeEnabled
placeholder={{
number: CLAUSE.CARD_NUMBER,
}}
cardStyle={styles.cardStyle}
style={styles.containerStyle}
onCardChange={info => setCardData(info)}
/>

The problem I am facing is with invalid expiry year and zip code. If I enter expiry year that is smaller than current year i.e 23 and below, the text becomes red demonstrating that I have entered invalid year which is correct.

But when I enter invalid year that is in upper limits like 80 or above, then UI text doesn't become red and info returned denotes valid expiry year but when I execute payment stripe payment fails giving me "Invalid attributes" error.

Card info response:
 {"brand": "Visa", "complete": true, "expiryMonth": 12, "expiryYear": 85, "last4": "4242", "postalCode": "11111", "validCVC": "Valid", "validExpiryDate": "Valid", "validNumber": "Valid"}

You can see that expiryYear is 85 but validExpiryDate is true.
Similarly for zipcode, zip code is acceptable irrespective of number of characters I enter.

This is a two step process.
First, Stripe does some basic checks on the user input, like if the expiry is in the past, or if the card number match the Luhn's algorithm. If any of these checks fail, then you will see the error highlighted in the form.
Second, Stripe sends the card information to the banks, and the banks will do more advanced checks on their end. If the bank declines the payment, then you will get back an error, but the specific error won't be highlighted in the form.
So what you see is expected.

But stripe library for react (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js) returns proper errors regarding year and zipcode.
